# tree structure keep reversion

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a tree structure in the form (code, parent code,title) that I created with C# and sql database.
I want to save the history changes, whenever a change occurs in the nodes of this structure.
That way, the user can reconstruct the previous tree structure if they want to see the previous structure.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: How you access db from application layer ? Do you use any ORM ?

Comment: Create a tracking table with the same structure + a historic date and a trigger linked to your original table that logs all operations to this new tracking table.

Comment: That's a hierarchy, not a tree structure. This matters because you can use a `hierarchyid` type instead of the `parent-child` relation. Data versioning is an entirely different problem though. You are asking how to version the entire table, not a single node or even a single path

Comment: Use a DML trigger to track the changes whenever an insert or update happens. In the history table store the primary key of the transaction table along with the changedate as datetime value. This would give you the complete history of the past changes.

Comment: A `hierarchyid` is essentially a path to the root, so keeping older values in a history or temporal table would preserve that path *only*. It won't preserve paths to children or the rest of the hierarchy

Comment: You don't need a tracking table nor triggers in SQL Server 2016 and later. It introduced [system-versioned temporal tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-2017) that keep track of changes automatically. That *doesn't* solve the bigger problem though. Maybe you can use a temporal table together with a `Version ID` field that would help you track *all* of the nodes changed in a single batch operation

Comment: Use a history table to convert the columns and their values into XML and store in an column with XML data type along with audit columns like datetime and identity as primary key. You can retain all the hierarchy and replace de serializing it when ever needed.

Comment: Tempoal tables can be used if your sql server version is 2016.

Comment: I'm connected to ADO.NET and the data is in the DataTable and the tree structure is created with it. I use SQL Server 2014. Currently, this structure is in use and its change will cause problems, so I'm not going to change it now. But the idea of creating a date field is right for me to be created in a similar table. I do not understand the English language well. Please refer to the code sample   Thank.